# Automatically disable wifi (wireless) when 'x seconds' since last browser page change

Tags: gnome, network-manager, firefox-extensions

Is it possible to create a script like this?

I'm asking because i suspect that the wifi power manangent in my ancient hardware is *really really* bad. To the point that while i had no internet, my power bill mysteriously dropped by 20€.

I suppose this idea would be better served as a firefox extension with permission to kill the network, but i dunno how to do that.

I don't care about other network connections than the browser, as long as it's easy to disable the script.

Answer (score 0):

The Wi-Fi on your computer probably costs less than the Wi-Fi on your router. This [website](https://www.makeitcheaper.com.au/news/how-much-energy-is-your-wi-fi-router-using) says:

> Taking a standard rate of 21.63 cents per kilowatt hour, you can
>   therefore expect your Wi-Fi router to cost around $0.0311 per day to
>   operate.

$20 per month (or 20 Euros in your case) is about what an air-conditioner would cost in a month. That draws 1200-1500 watts whereas an average laptop draws [15 to 60 watts](http://michaelbluejay.com/electricity/computers.html) and an average desktop about [130 watts](https://www.griffith.edu.au/sustainability/sustainable-campuses/sustainable-initiatives/energy/average-computer-energy-usage).

I just read that Wi-Fi cards in desktops draw about [0.3 to 0.8 Watts](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/ethernet-card-vs-wifi-power-consumption.2384201/) which is almost nothing when you consider the average light bulb is 60 Watts.

YMMV - Your Mileage May Vary.